# How to create PolicyEnvelope for a custom checkin policy in visual studio 2010?

Tags: tfs, checkin-policy

I create a custom checkin policy for TFS 2010 in visual studio 2010. The policy itself in working great. Now, I am trying to apply the custom policy from code. Below is my code:

```
try
        {
            var projectCollectionUri = new Uri("https://mydomain.com/tfs");
            var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri, new UICredentialsProvider());
            projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

            var vcs = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            var teamProject = vcs.GetTeamProject("myProject");

            foreach (PolicyType policyType in Workstation.Current.InstalledPolicyTypes)
            {
                if (policyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("MyPolicyType"))
                {
                    //teamProject.SetCheckinPolicies(new PolicyEnvelope[] { new PolicyEnvelope(workItemPolicy, policyType) });
                    //break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

I am stuck at this line:

```
//teamProject.SetCheckinPolicies(new PolicyEnvelope[] { new PolicyEnvelope(workItemPolicy, policyType) });
```

How can I create the policy envelope for my custom policy? The code I am referencing is from the below location:
http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/02/team-foundation-server-2010-enable.html

Comment: Does your Policy implement `IPolicyDefenition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the `WorkItemPolicy` in the example with your policy:

For example:

```
var myPolicy = new MyPolicy();

foreach (PolicyType policyType in Workstation.Current.InstalledPolicyTypes)
{
    if (policyType.Name == myPolicy.Type)
    {
        teamProject.SetCheckinPolicies(
            new PolicyEnvelope[]
            {
                new PolicyEnvelope(myPolicy, policyType)
            });
        break;
    }
}
```

You may need to add a reference to the assembly containing your policy if you do not have it in you Console Application.

Comment: Oh ya...I missed on the simple thing. Your solution worked great. But, my approach here is removing all the existing checkin policies and only enabling the one that is specified in this code. What I am trying to do is, the code I write should add the specified checkin policy to the existing list, but not replace the whole list with the specified policy.

Comment: I got it. `teamProject.GetCheckinPolicies()` returns the array of `PolicyEnvolope` object. Then in the 'if' block, I am adding my policy to this array object and then passing this array object to `teamProject.SetCheckinPolicies()` will do the work I need.  Thanks for your help Dave.